# Include a specific column in pandas groupby output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

The below dataframe gives me the following results where I have filtered on the top 4 performing 'source_id'

```
df= highestrevenue.loc[highestrevenue['source_id'].isin(['PA0202','PA0057','PA0873','PA0678'])]
print(df)


           date source_id    cost  revenue
 3322 2014-01-11    PA0202  9637.0  12000.0
3176 2014-01-17    PA0057  1691.0  11999.0
4748 2014-10-14    PA0873  8376.0  11995.0
752  2014-05-30    PA0678  9739.0  11992.0
5442 2014-02-13    PA0202  4157.0  11954.0
...         ...       ...     ...      ...
9800 2014-02-09    PA0873   989.0      NaN
9855 2014-06-20    PA0873  6407.0      NaN
9857 2014-03-01    PA0202  7104.0      NaN
9897 2014-07-14    PA0057  7231.0      NaN
9946 2014-01-08    PA0057  2308.0      NaN

[789 rows x 4 columns]
```

I wanted the date column to be organized in months which gives me sum of revenue for each month, I have used

```
df_plot.groupby(df_plot['date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['revenue'].sum().sort_values()
```

that gives me

```
 date
February     123702.0
April        136110.0
July         145350.0
March        178350.0
October      199992.0
September    203631.0
December     204183.0
January      209337.0
August       231515.0
November     233001.0
May          267656.0
June         277374.0
```

But, I wanted 3 columns, date by months, Revenue and source_id(4)
so that further I am able to make a line graph , with x-axis as months, y-axis as revenue and 4 lines showing the 4 source id's

for now, how do i get the third column thats the source_id in in the above dataframe???

expected output dataframe is

```
date  Revenue  source_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group on both date and ID:

```
(df_plot.groupby([df_plot['date'].dt.strftime('%B'), 'source_id'])['revenue']
        .sum()
        .sort_index())
```